# mssql revert changes made today without backup

Tags: sql-server, rollback

A bug in an app made some changes now i need to rollback without a backup

Can i use the logfile for this ?

Is 'ROLLBACK' another option ?

> **INFO:**
>
> -My Recovery model is set to simple
>
> -AutoCommit hasnt been set
>
> -When i try to use the restore task, it tells me 'no backupset selected to be restored'

Comment: Rollback is only an option before commit and the application must have committed or nobody would see the changes. I very much doubt that you can restore without a backup.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> My Recovery model is set to simple

In short, there is nothing you can do but learn from this lesson that important databases should use the full recovery model (along with proper restore plans).

> Can i use the logfile for this

Since it's in the simple recovery model, most likely not.

> Is 'ROLLBACK' another option ?

Only if the transaction is currently open and it's a single transaction. If it's been committed, nope.